# Cordova android build doesn't fire deavice ready

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have ionic cordova project for iOS and Android,

I have an issue with Android build, the app doesn't fire device ready and I see the warning that it didn't fire after 5 seconds, and it never fires.

`Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms`

However, if I run the project to the emulator or connected device it works just fine! the issue only appears with the build and only on android.

I have tried removing the plugin and installing them again, same for the platform, I tried removing plugins and build, non changed that!

- Angular 8
- Android 10
- Ionic 5

I have no idea what else I should try, no errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going step by step recreation I was able to find the cause in config.xml, it was this line:

`<preference name="Scheme" value="custom" />`

For more details about it
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/blob/master/README.md#scheme

Hope that helps other, I wasted days on this issue :(